# Use netCDF file in R as panel data sf object

Tags: r, netcdf, r-sf

I have a netCDF file from:
Kummu, Matti; Taka, Maija; Guillaume, Joseph H. A. (2020), Data from: Gridded global datasets for Gross Domestic Product and Human Development Index over 1990-2015, Dryad, Dataset, https://doi.org/10.5061/dryad.dk1j0

More specifically, I want to use this dataset:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-PUa0R0ZcUCJbA1VIMe0KKdElHX2C3Cc/view?usp=sharing
which is in netCDF format.
I would like to import it as a panel dataset sf-object such that I can spatia-join it with a different sf-object.
I tried using

```
ppp <- stars::read_stars('~/GDP_per_capita_PPP_1990_2015_v2.nc', var="GDP_per_capita_PPP")
ppp <- sf::st_as_sf(ppp)
```

The result is a panel-dataset with over 9 million observations but the geometry seems to be off. I am only interested in African countries, maybe this helps reduce the dataset, but from the sf-object I get I do not know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below to combine the gridded gdp with the centroid of an administrative region (which was an SF object - represented by `obj2` in the code snippet).

If you need to aggregate the grids into an administrative region (say by averaging over the region), have a look at [exactextractr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/exactextractr/readme/README.html)

```
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(terra)

obj1 <- stack("./doi_10.5061_dryad.dk1j0__v2/GDP_per_capita_PPP_1990_2015_v2.nc")

extract.df <- terra::extract(obj1, obj2, df = T)
```

Comment: So I just use the shapefile with the observations (e.g. administrative districts) I want the variables to correspond to as ```obj2```?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not being more explicit - ```obj2```is the shape file that you want to merge the other data with. This is pretty fast if obj2 is a set of points. If you have polygons instead, then you have to dig a bit into the documentation to see how to aggregate over the polygon.

Comment: My ```obj2``` is a shapefile made up of polygons, I am running the code ```extract.df <- terra::extract(obj1, obj2, df = T)``` at the moment but the calculations are taking quite some time

Comment: The exactextractr package worked much faster for my data. The function call looks something like ```exact_extract(obj1, obj2, 'mean', stack_apply = F)```. Hope this helps!